# How to place figures and tables in a strange journal style

Tags: journal-publishing

My colleague is writing a paper for [this journal](https://www.scirp.org/journal/JSS/). They use a rather strange format with wide left margin, combined with two-sided headers, see for ex. [this paper](https://www.scirp.org/pdf/jss_2024013014234306.pdf).
They sent her a LaTeX template and it creates the left margin by putting white-coloured `\lipsum` into a `wraptable`...

Strange as it is, the template works, except that I do not know how to place figures and table so that they will stay in the text column - normal floating environments span the whole `textwidth`, while the published papers have figures aligned with the text column, as seen in the [mentioned paper](https://www.scirp.org/pdf/jss_2024013014234306.pdf). (Though I have seen other papers using a full-width tables, so that is acceptable if the table is too wide for the column.)

Here, I post an MWE with an edited version of the template, together with my best attempts to place a figure in it:

```latex
\documentclass[a4 paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}                           % Makes the page margins smaller to a predefined one.
\usepackage[lmargin=0.6in,rmargin=0.6in,tmargin=0.6in,headsep=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs} % To produce the empty space on the left
\usepackage{xtab} % To produce the empty space on the left
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsfonts,graphicx}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont+={bf,color=Brown},singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty
\allsectionsfont{\color{Brown}}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
{\csname the#1\endcsname\;}%  default
{\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% individual control
}
\def\section@cntformat{\thesection.\;} % Dot after the section number
\def\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\;} % Dot after the subsection number
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor = black}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%  ---------------   Normal Headers  ------------------
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsf{W. S. Khedr}}
%\fancyhead[C]{Paper Title: Running Title}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Scientific Research Publishing}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} % to remove line on header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} % to remove line on footer
% ------------------ Header for first page -----------------
\fancypagestyle{first}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyhead[L]{Scientific Research Publishing}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{{\footnotesize \textsf{DOI: \href{10.4236/***.2024.*****}{\color{blue}\uline{10.4236/***.2024.*****}} $\;$**** **, 2024}}}%
  \fancyhead[R]{{\bf\small \textsf{Journal of ****, 2024, *, *-*}}\\
\href{http://www.scirp.org/journal/***}{\color{blue}\uline{\textsf{http://www.scirp.org/journal/***}}}\\
\textsf{ISSN Online:****-****}\\
\textsf{ISSN Print:****-****}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% to remove line on header
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% to remove line on footer
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{first}
\vspace*{3cm}
%%%%%%%%%  TITLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\noindent\huge\bf Classical Fundamental Unique Solution for the Incompressible Navier-Stokes Equation in $\mathbb{R}^N$}\\[1cm]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Author Data %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\bf\large Waleed S. Khedr}\\[0.5cm]
Independent Researcher, Cairo, Egypt\\
Email: waleedshawki@yahoo.com\\
%%%%%%%%%%%   The Information Bar on the Left %%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{wraptable}{l}{5.1cm}
{\footnotesize
\begin{xtabular*}{0.3\textwidth}{p{5cm}}
\noindent{\bf How to cite this paper:} Khedr, W. S. (2024) Classical Fundamental Unique Solution for the Incompressible Navier-Stokes Equation in $\mathbb{R}^N$, Journal of ***, {\bf *},    *-*.\\
\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/***.2024.*****}\\
{\bf Received: **** **, ***}\\
{\bf Accepted: **** **, ***}\\
{\bf Published: **** **, ***}\\
Copyright \copyright$\;$2024 by author(s) and Scientific Research Publishing Inc.\\
This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution International License (CC BY 4.0).\\
\url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/}\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% IMPORTANT FOR AUTHORS %%%%%%%%
% Copy and paste the following line depending on the number of full pages in your document (i.e. before using the template)
{\color{white}\lipsum[1-60]}% If the number of pages is less than 15
%{\color{white}\lipsum[1-60]}% uncomment if the number of pages is more than 15 and less than 30
%{\color{white}\lipsum[1-60]}% uncomment if the number of pages is more than 30 and less than 45
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{xtabular*}
}
\end{wraptable}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  The Abstract and Keywords %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\color{Brown}\rule{0.7\textwidth}{2pt}}\\[0.2cm]
{\color{Brown}\bf\large Abstract}\\
\lipsum[1]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  The Document Starts Here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
    \caption{Image ‘example-image-16x9’ from package mwe.}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

We can see that Fig~\ref{fig:1} spans the whole width of the page\dots
\lipsum[1-1]

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

Image ‘example-image-a’ has the correct width, but no caption\dots
\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{Image ‘example-image-b’ from package mwe.}
    \label{fig:b}
\end{minipage}

Fig.~\ref{fig:b} is using minipage. It has the correct width, but does not respect the column\dots
\lipsum[1-1]

\noindent
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \captionof{figure}{Image ‘example-image-b’ from package mwe.}
    \label{fig:c}
    \bigskip
}

Fig.~\ref{fig:c} is using parbox and respects the column -- but one has to be careful with placement\dots
\lipsum[1-1]

\noindent
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \medskip
    \captionof{table}{Dummy table with caption}
    \label{tbl:test}
    \centering
    \vspace{-1ex}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
        abc & def \\
        qwerty & asdfg \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \bigskip
}

Table~\ref{tbl:test} is also using parbox\dots
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

There, you can see that the best I could do was to place the figures in a `\parbox` - but this requires careful placement around page borders, otherwise one gets a lot of wasted vertical space.
In this sense, it would be better to do it with something floating...

Another alternative is to ignore the template's solution and replicate the design using variable margin and header definitions, but I did not manage to do that. The biggest issues were:

- getting the first page correct, including the left block
- have text with left-side margin, but headers and footers that span the whole width and have alternating formatting on odd and even pages

Comment: From the linked journal: To expedite the review process, please format the manuscript in the following way:  Article type:
**One Column**  [...]  All manuscripts are expected to be prepared as a single PDF or MS Word document [...] LaTex paper is also acceptable for publication, but it should be in PDF for review first.  The editor does not ask to send the manuscript ready to print, just an acceptable source. Just take care of making figures and tables that do not need be shrunken or stretched too munch in the final format.

Comment: @Fran: Good point, but I would still hesitate to submit a paper with misplaced figures and tables, it simply does not look right...

Comment: The reviiewers could care less about the final format.  They are there to judge content, not style.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Pity they don't have the LaTeX code as it is a nice template. Not difficult to replicate to be honest, but it is easier if all the measurements etc are avalble.

Comment: @MichalKaut I didn't say that floats have to be misplaced, but as long as there are cross-references in the text  clearly indicating  where each float is relevant, even  it could be appreciated have all of them at the end. Keep in mind that the richer the layout  you give, the harder it will be to undo it by whoever has to do the final layout.  And as said, the referees don't care about the  layout. Usually they want  enumerated and well spaced lines to comment comfortably, not any kind of final layout.